# Constructing a graph where any node can have the highest PageRank among all nodes

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, ranking

I'm trying to solve q5.1.4 in [mmds chapter5](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch5a.pdf), however, I'm not sure how I can even start. The question is:

Construct, for any integer n, a Web such that, depending on
β, any of the n nodes can have the highest PageRank among those n. It is
allowed for there to be other nodes in the Web besides these n.

I would've attached my work so far but as I said I'm not sure where to start from.